Unable to see ticket details after creating the ticket in OTRS v7
I am using OTRS v7 and have created a new process. However, while testing it, I see that when I create a ticket and submit and Open the ticket on my end, I can't see the ticket details in the ticket body.
it shows as No Articles found here.
As per my knowledge, I need to update the newly created dynamic fields in the sys config however, unable to find in which to update the fields. Please help.
